# Выборка данных из массива

Tags: php

Есть переменная

```
$mas = array('1', '2', '5');
```

Формируется в зависимости от нужных значений **id** категорий.
Также имеется вот такой массив, используется для хранения инфы о категориях

```
array {
   [1]=> array {
      ["id"]=> "1"
      ["parent_id"]=> ""
      ["name"]=> "color"
   }
   [2]=> array {
      ["id"]=> "2"
      ["parent_id"]=> "1"
      ["name"]=> "blue"
   }
   [3]=> array {
      ["id"]=> "3"
      ["parent_id"]=> "1"
      ["name"]=> "orange"
   }
   [4]=> array {
      ["id"]=> "4"
      ["parent_id"]=> "1"
      ["name"]=> "gray"
   }
   [5]=> array {
      ["id"]=> "5"
      ["parent_id"]=> "1"
      ["name"]=> "yellow"
   }
}
```

Подскажите, как вывести именно ключи из **$mas**

Comment: Ключами в массиве $mas будут индексы 0,1,2,... Вам это нужно?

Comment: Ключи будут различными, то есть если страница относится к категориям 1,2 и 5, то получить хочу `array {
   [1]=> array {
      ...
   }
   [2]=> array {
      ...
   }

   [5]=> array {
       ...
   }
}`

Comment: http://php.net/array-keys

Comment: А во втором маcсиве верхний индекс всегда равен id ? Или вы не по id выбрать хотите, а именно по индексам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вариант - простой для понимания.
Предположим второй массив будет **$mas2**

```
foreach ($mas as $mas_value) {
  $result_mas[$mas_value]=$mas2[$mas_value];
}
```

В переменной $result_mas будет Ваш массив, ну а дальше крутите как хотите.

Второй вариант "элегантный", как в подсказал в комментариях [@ArchDemon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/31819/archdemon) через array_keys думаю тоже сработает, но я спросонья сразу не соображу, надо потестить.

Comment: Действительно, просто и доступно, как это я сам не догадался-то, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Страшненько, но работает :) Думаю, тут всё понятно

```
$mas1 = [1,3];
$mas2 = [['id'=>5],['id'=>4],['id'=>3],['id'=>2],['id'=>1]];

print_r(array_intersect_key($mas2, array_intersect(array_column($mas2, 'id'), $mas1))); // [ [id => 3], [id => 1] ]
```

**[демо тут](https://eval.in/781040)**